# .confirmationDialog inside of .swipeActions does not work, iOS 15

Tags: swiftui, xcode13, ios15

With regards to iOS 15, Xcode 13; I am wondering if this is a bug, not properly implemented, or a planned non-functional feature...

With a list that has a `.swipeActions` that calls a `.confirmationDialog` the confirmation dialog does not show.

See example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var confirmDelete = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                ForEach(1..<10) {_ in
                    Cell()
                }

                .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                    Button(role: .destructive) {
                        confirmDelete.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                    }

                    .confirmationDialog("Remove this?", isPresented: $confirmDelete) {
                        Button(role: .destructive) {
                            print("Removed!")
                        } label: {
                            Text("Yes, Remove this")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Cell: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Misconfiguration:***

The view modifier `.confirmationDialog` needs to be added to the view that is ***outside*** of the `.swipeActions` view modifier. It works when configured properly as shown below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var confirmDelete = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                ForEach(1..<10) {_ in
                    Cell()
                }
                .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                    Button(role: .destructive) {
                        confirmDelete.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                    }
                }
                //move outside the scope of the .swipeActions view modifier:
                .confirmationDialog("Remove this?", isPresented: $confirmDelete) {
                    Button(role: .destructive) {
                        print("Removed!")
                    } label: {
                        Text("Yes, Remove this")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Cell: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: On the iPad, it shows a popover but the popover points to wrong cell. It gives the impression a different cell is deleted

Comment: @user1046037 I believe I ran into this same issue. I think it is because that is where the popover shows on iPad for any item. I just added a custom message in that popover to confirm you are deleting the correct item, such as “Delete item X?”. That makes things a bit more clear.

Comment: That is a probable workaround, thanks, but it still feels like a SwiftUI bug, ideally the adding the `confirmationDialog` to the swipe button should but doesn't work